# Can a struct be sent and received in named pipe?

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, process, named-pipes

I have an excercise for operating system subject.

Question is: Create two process P0 and P1. P0 read a squared matrix from input file, then send to pipe. P1 read matrix from pipe, invert it and write to output file. If the inputted matrix can not be inverted, P1 write a message to output file and return

My code is below. I compiled with

```
gcc -Wall main.c -o main.out
```

the program keeps "Segmentation fault (Core dumped)"

Please help me find where i failed. Sorry for my bad English

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

#define FIFO1 "/tmp/ff.1"
#define FIFO2 "/tmp/ff.2"
#define PM 0666
#define PIPE_BUF 10240
#define SIGN(x) ((x%2)? -1:1)

extern int errno;

/*
matrix struct insist of 
size and a two-dimension array
*/
typedef struct {
    int size;
    float** array;
} matrix_t;

/*
prototypes
of some functions
*/
matrix_t readMatrix(char* filename);
void writeMatrix(char* filename, matrix_t matrix);
matrix_t invertMatrix(matrix_t matrix);
float detOfMatrix(float** arr, int size);
float** allocArr(int szRow, int szCol);
void FreeMem(float ** buff, int n);
/*
main here
return -1 if fork() == -1
return -3 if there is no pipe created
*/
int main(void) {
    //FILE *in, *out;

    //int fd[2];
    char input[] = "/home/thao/ass1/input.txt";
    char output[] = "/home/thao/ass1/output.txt";
    matrix_t sendmatrix, receivematrix, invertedmatrix;
    int childpid, readfd, writefd;
    if ((mknod(FIFO1, S_IFIFO | PM, 0) < 0) && (errno!=EEXIST)) {
        printf("Ko tao duoc fifo1 \n");
        return -1; 
    }
    if ((mknod(FIFO2, S_IFIFO | PM, 0) < 0) && (errno!=EEXIST)) {
        unlink(FIFO1);
        printf("Ko tao duoc fifo2 \n");
        return -1;
    }

    switch(childpid = fork()) {
        case -1: 
            printf("Ko tao duoc process\n");
            return -2;
        case 0: //Child
            if((readfd = open(FIFO1, 0)) < 0)
                perror("Child, ko mo duoc readfido\n");
            read(readfd, &receivematrix, PIPE_BUF);
            int det;
            if ((det = detOfMatrix(receivematrix.array, receivematrix.size)) == 0.0) {
                FILE *out = fopen(output, "w");
                fprintf(out, "Ma tran khong nghich dao duoc\n");
                return -1;
            }
            else {
                invertedmatrix = invertMatrix(receivematrix);   
                writeMatrix(output, invertedmatrix);
            }
            close(readfd);
        default: //Parent
            if ((writefd = open(FIFO1, 1)) < 0)
                perror("Parent, ko mo duoc writefifo\n");
            sendmatrix = readMatrix(input);
            write(writefd, &sendmatrix, PIPE_BUF);
            while(wait((int*)0) != childpid);
            close(writefd);
            if (unlink(FIFO1) < 0)
                perror("Khong the xoa ten FIFO1 tu file system\n");
            if (unlink(FIFO2) < 0) 
                perror ("Ko the xoa ten FIFO2 tu file system\n");
    }
    return 0;
}

/*
Function: invert matrix
Parameters: struct of matrix
Return: inverted matrix - type struct of matrix
*/
matrix_t invertMatrix (matrix_t matrix) {
    matrix_t result;
    result.size = matrix.size;
    result.array = matrix.array;
    float det = detOfMatrix(matrix.array, matrix.size);
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.size; i++) 
        for (j = 0; j < matrix.size; j++) 
            result.array[i][j] = (1/det) * matrix.array[i][j];
    return result;
}

/*
Function: read matrix from input
Parameters: path of input file
Return: struct of matrix
*/
matrix_t readMatrix(char* filename) {
    FILE *in = fopen(filename, "r");
    char buf[10000];
    matrix_t matrix;
    int size = 0;
    matrix.array = 0;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while(fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), in)) {
        size += 1;
        for (j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            fscanf(in,"%f", &matrix.array[i][j]);
            printf("%f\t",matrix.array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
    matrix.size = size;
    return matrix;
}

/*
Function: write matrix to output
Parameters: path of output file, struct of matrix
Return: void
*/
void writeMatrix(char* filename, matrix_t matrix) {
    FILE *out = fopen(filename, "wb");
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.size; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matrix.size; j++) {
            fprintf(out,"%f\t", matrix.array[i][j]);
            printf("%f\t",matrix.array[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(out,"\n");
        printf("\n");
    }
    fclose(out);
}

/*
Function: calculate determinant of matrix
Parameters: struct of matrix
Return: determinant of matrix - type float 
*/
float detOfMatrix(float** arr, int size) {
    float result = 0;
    int m, n, i, j, k;

    float** subArr;
    if (size < 2) 
        return -1;
    if (size == 2)
        return arr[0][0] * arr[1][1] - arr[1][0] * arr[0][1];
    else {
        if (!(subArr = allocArr(size - 1, size - 1))) 
            return -1;
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            m = n = 0;
            for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
                for (k = 0; k < size; k++) {
                    if (k != i) {
                        subArr[m][n] = arr[j][k];
                        n++;
                        if (n == size - 1) {
                            m++;
                            n = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        result += SIGN(i) * arr[0][i]*detOfMatrix(subArr, size - 1);
        }
        FreeMem(subArr, size - 1);
        return result;  
    }
}

/*
Function: Allocate memory for array
*/
float ** allocArr(int szRow, int szCol) {
    int i;
    float **pArr;
    pArr = (float**)malloc(szRow * sizeof(float *));
    if (!pArr)
        return NULL;
    for (i = 0; i < szRow; i++) {
        pArr[i] = (float*)malloc(szCol * sizeof(float *));
        if (!pArr[i])
            return NULL;
    }
    return pArr;
}

/*
Function: free allocated memory
Parameters: pointer to memory
Return: void
*/
void FreeMem(float ** buff, int n) {
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (buff[i])
        {
            free(buff[i]);
            buff[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    if (buff)
        free(buff);
}
```

Comment: Yes you can send a structure over a pipe. The problem is that you can't send *pointers* to an unrelated process. A pointer is unique to a specific process and can't be passed to other unrelated processes. You have to figure out a way to transmit the actual data.

Comment: Another problem is that you don't seem to be allocating memory for the pointer in the `matrix_t` structure. You never make it point anywhere. That will lead to *undefined behavior* and is most likely the reason you have the crash.

Comment: Never write `extern int errno;` in code; it has been outlawed by POSIX for the whole of the current millennium.  You must use `#include <errno.h>` to gain access to `errno`.  Only old books and code contain that line and it is not safe in the modern world.

Comment: The reason to not write `extern int errno;` in code that `errno` is often defined as something like `#define errno (*thread_local_errno())` where `thread_local_errno` is a function that returns the address that the current thread's `errno` values are stored.  If a regular `int errno` is used then multiple threads could get their error values mixed up.

Comment: Thank you guys so much for replying me. I understand all of your comments. Thank a lot :D